# Is it possible to join one table to another, where one column in the first table matches one of multiple columns in the second?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL database with two tables, `People` and `Itinerary`.

`People` table columns:

- ...
- `Item1`
- `Item2`
- `Item3`
- ...

`Itinerary` table columns:

- `ID`
- `COLUMN2`
- ...

In the people table, the columns `Item1`, `Item2`, and `Item3` match values in the `ID` column  for some row in the `Itinerary` table.

Is it possible to join the itinerary table to all three `Item_` columns? E.g., something like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Itinerary.COLUMN2
FROM    People
        JOIN Itinerary ON People.ITEM1 = Itinerary.ID
        JOIN Itinerary ON People.ITEM2 = Itinerary.ID
        JOIN Itinerary ON People.ITEM3 = Itinerary.ID
```

Note that the above query doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want by using `or` or `in` in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ITINERARY.COLUMN2
FROM People pl JOIN
     Itinerary i
     ON i.ID IN (pl.ITEM1, pl.ITEM2, pl.ITEM3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question entirely, but maybe something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Itinerary.COLUMN2

FROM People
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Itinerary ON
    (
        Itinerary.ID = People.ITEM1
        OR Itinerary.ID = People.ITEM2
        OR Itinerary.ID = People.ITEM3
    )
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! My mistake. Must have been thinking in pseudocode.